# Problems with gradle dependencies and apache POI - CellType

Tags: java, apache, gradle

I am relatively new to using gradle, and am having trouble understanding dependencies. I have been using the Apache POI library to read from excel for a project, and initially I downloaded the JARs into my project and it worked completely fine. I decided to use gradle dependencies when I put my project on GitLab (from what I understand it is the same as using JARs but better when sharing the project since you don't have to download them?). This worked for most of the imports; however, for some reason my project is no longer able to import CellType. I redownloaded the JARs for the time being and it works again.

 A summary of the question(s): 
Why is CellType the only thing that stopped working, and why did it stop working? What is different about it?

Edit: here is the dependencies section from my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev499-1.23.0'
testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.9.10'
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.8.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6
compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-java6', version: '1.11.0-beta'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty
compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.11.0-beta'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.17'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
```

(Sorry for the messiness :/ )

The compile error I was getting was something like "cannot resolve" (the import statement was turning red)

`import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;`

Comment: Unfortunately people who answer stack overflow questions aren't mind readers. Please include relevant snippets from `build.gradle` and perhaps the compile error

Comment: Oops, sorry! I edited with relevant info. I found a way to get around using CellType so I am no longer getting the error; however I am still interested in knowing why I was getting this issue. Thanks! :)